# $watch does not work when changing scope variables inside a service

Tags: angularjs

I am using a service to change some of scope A's variables. When I try to `$watch` for changes on those variables nothing happens.

The basic setup is shown below. I would like to use `$watch` in my own custom directive that I add to the element. But if that is impossible I would at least like to be able to use `$watch` from inside the controller.

I made a [plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qoC4WICY4BVKiTkV9RZG?p=preview). As you can see `$scope.someVar` changes but $watch is never fired on either the controller or the directive.

[image]

```
app.factory("changerService", function() {
  var $scope;
  function change(to) {
    $scope.someVar = to;
  }
  function setScope(scope) {
    $scope = scope;
  }
  return {
    Change: change,
    SetScope: setScope
  }
});

app.controller("bar", ["$scope", "changerService", function ($scope, changerService) {
    $scope.someVar = true;
    changerService.SetScope($scope);
    $scope.showImg = function (val) {
        changerService.Change(val);
        $scope.state = $scope.someVar;
    };

    $scope.$watch($scope.someVar, function (newVal, oldVal) {
        $scope.watchController = newVal ? newVal : "undefined";
    });
}]);

app.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(scope.someVar, function (newVal, oldVal) {
                scope.watchDirective = newVal ? newVal : "undefined";
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After examining your code i noticed that your watch expression is an object but it must be a string.

**Example:**

```
app.controller("bar", ["$scope", "changerService", function ($scope, changerService) {
    $scope.someVar = true;
    changerService.SetScope($scope);
    $scope.showImg = function (val) {
        changerService.Change(val);
        $scope.state = $scope.someVar;
    };

    $scope.$watch("someVar", function (newVal, oldVal) {
        $scope.watchController = newVal ? newVal : "undefined";
    });
}]);

app.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch("someVar", function (newVal, oldVal) {
                scope.watchDirective = newVal ? newVal : "undefined";
            });
        }
    }
});
```